# Query textfile for specific string

Tags: windows, scripting, juniper-network-connect

I’m not sure where to start with this one so apologies in advance if it seems confused.

I would like to query the contents of a .DAT file (.txt format) for a specific text string. Ideally it needs to return an error level so I can then determine a follow up command if required. I’m not sure this kind of thing is possible?

I’ll give the scenario for more context. I am required to update the connection settings for Juniper VPN clients on End User Devices. I only want to update clients which don’t have a specific text string in the connection file (.DAT file). So I’d like to put together a script which first queries the connection file and then runs a command based on the response of the query.

From the research I’ve already done, this kind of thing only seems to be possible with SQL. I have considered going down the route of comparing one file with another but I think that is too open to false negatives.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update

I've managed to use PowerShell to query the file:

```
get-content -path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Juniper Networks\ConnectionStore\connstore.bak' | where-object {$_ -like '*DR Connection*'}
 friendly-name: "DR Connection"
```

Comment: Why don't you ask about the problem you are trying to solve rather than the solution you have in mind (which is way too fuzzy to even know, whether it's applicable, but probably not).

Comment: Hi. I have given the scenario of the problem for context.

Comment: Neither *".DAT"* nor *".txt"* are file formats. Those are extensions, and the contents could be **anything**. What syntax do those files have? XML? INI format? Something else? And what scripting environment are you using? Batch? PowerShell? Something else?

Comment: They are INI format. So far I have attempted to use Batch and VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would post my final script which solved my problem just in case anybody else has come across this issue.

```
#File to search for along with what word to search for
$File = Get-Content "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Juniper Networks\ConnectionStore\connstore.bak" | Where-Object { $_.Contains("remotedr") }

#read-host -Prompt "Proceed?"
#write-host "Contents of var: $file"

#If the $file variable is NULL, then run the .BAT file
If($file -eq $null) {
write-host "Launching BAT file..."
    Start-Process -FilePath 'JuniperConfig.cmd' -Wait
#.BAT file will run until it finishes, then the script will continue
}

#Otherwise, do nothing
Else {
write-host "Do nothing"
}

#write-host
#read-host "Pausing. Press ENTER to continue."
```

Thanks